# Push out advert effect with jquery

Tags: jquery

I would like to make an advertisement to my site. Previously i seen a solution when user visit a site, the advert will push out the hole page from right to left. 
Is it possible to make it work with jquery?

thanks

Comment: Probably yes. Do you have an example? Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: It is possible (and not too difficult). The users will hate you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use animate for that:

[Go to Jquery Animate](http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/animate)

run the demos to view the animation

Comment: Needs more detail. Animate what, where...

Comment: checkout the examples provided in the above url and try to run the demos.